# ASP.NET and ActiveDirectory General access denied error

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7, active-directory

I have ASP.NET page to manage objects in ActiveDirectory. I use this [class](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/90142/Everything-in-Active-Directory-via-Csharp-NET-3-5-.aspx)
I can create a user object in AD successfully in my dev machine. When I deployed it to the server, I can only edit existing objects but I **canNOT
create a new user**. I always get this exception General access denied error.

Is there any setting that I missed? Please help. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using static credentials within IIS? Then ensure that the account has the required permissions to create new objects.

Are you using impersonation with IIS? Then make sure you're using the correct authentication setup. You can not use the default Windows authentication if you're trying to authenticate against another machine (your domain servers). That's called the [Double-Hop Problem](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/knowledgecast/archive/2007/01/31/the-double-hop-problem.aspx), and has been [mentioned before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4071929/how-do-i-configure-iis-so-that-the-users-domain-credentials-are-used-when-connec/4072300#4072300), usually related to SQL Server and trusted connections, but will also affect any attempt to use the impersonated users credentials against other machines.

Comment: I used static credentials within the app. Silly me, I just figured out that I have two functions, one without static credentials. Thanks for suggestion.